# Animate element only if position is not 0

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make `ul#pikame` move right it its relative position IS 0, but it keeps moving right even if position is not 0.

I know `li_left` is set to 0 at the beginning, and it remembers that and sticks to it, but I need `li_left` to update for each new click.

My code:

```
li_left = $('ul#pikame').css('left');
if (li_left == '0px') {
    $('a.prev').click(function (e) {
        // e.preventDefault();
        $('ul#pikame').animate({
            'left': '+=127'
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

to sum up, it should move right only ONCE, because after the first click the position left will not be 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition should be inside the click handler, not outside.

```
$('a.prev').click(function (e) {
    li_left = $('ul#pikame').css('left');
    if (li_left == '0px') {
        // e.preventDefault();
        $('ul#pikame').animate({
        'left': '+=127'
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (li_left == 0) { ...
```

If you look at the value returned by `$('ul#pikame').css('left');` you will find that it is an integer. You're currently comparing it too a string literal of "0px", which is not equal.

Alternatively, it looks like you're trying to only perform the action once. If this is the case then you can use JQuery's [`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) function to perform the action - you guessed it - just once!

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/P2L5F/**

```
$('div').one('click', function() {
    $(this).animate({
        'left': '+=127'
    });
});
```